# Was there any valid criticism of Hegel's Phenomenology of Spirit?

Tags: hegel, phenomenology

I only saw criticisms levied against him from people who have never read the book, so I was wondering if there was any valid criticism levied against the ideas from the book.

Arthur Schopenhauer criticized Phenomenology of Spirit as being characteristic of the vacuous verbiage he attributed to Hegel.[22]

> Walter Kaufmann, on the question of organisation argued that Hegel's
>   arrangement "over half a century before Darwin published his Origin of
>   Species and impressed the idea of evolution on almost everybody's
>   mind, was developmental."[23] The idea is supremely suggestive but in
>   the end, untenable according to Kaufmann: "The idea of arranging all
>   significant points of view in such a single sequence, on a ladder that
>   reaches from the crudest to the most mature, is as dazzling to
>   contemplate as it is mad to try seriously to implement it".[24] While
>   Kaufmann viewed Hegel as right in seeing that the way a view is
>   reached is not necessarily external to the view itself; since on the
>   contrary a knowledge of the development, including the prior
>   positions, through which a human being passed before adopting a
>   position may make all the difference when it comes to comprehending
>   his or her position, some aspects of the conception are still somewhat
>   absurd and some of the details bizarre.[25] **Kaufmann also remarks that
>   the very table of contents of the Phenomenology may be said to 'mirror
>   confusion' and that "faults are so easy to find in it that it is not
>   worth while to adduce heaps of them."** However, he excuses Hegel since
>   he understands that the author of the Phenomenology "finished the book
>   under an immense strain".[26]

Like on the Wikipedia page, we only really see a criticism of the table of content, which is really absurd if you ask me.

I would like to see criticisms on the arguments used throughout the book.

Comment: I think you will find that Kaufmann was Popper's translator for the book in which Popper slammed Hegel. Here is Kaufmann on "The Hegel Myth and its Method". https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/us/kaufmann.htm

Comment: Scholarly studies of both Hegel and Marx continue. We are actually young in the day, particularly for Marx, since his writings were locked away in the USSR for some years. They are now in Amsterdam, I believe.

Comment: I don't have a good English copy of the book (French only). Neither public nor college library has it, but I found this interesting video on Youtube: *Diagram of Hegel's Phenomenology of Spirit* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Z1zY39EKbs

Comment: Two problems with the idea. First, PoS is an introduction to Hegel's system, if one is to criticize, it would make more sense to criticize the complete product rather than the introduction to it. Second, Hegel's reasoning there is rather obscure, and extracting something tangible enough to criticize will be subject to intractable interpretative challenges to the validity of the extraction. So the typical approach is charity, one only extracts what one can praise or credit, leaving the "criticism" to the oblivion.